# which version of @testing-library/cypress is compatible with cypress version 9.5.3?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, testing-library, cypress-testing-library

I am trying to install `@testing-library/cypress` with `cypress@9.5.3` already installed in my project.

It gives me a could not resolve dependency error.
It expects `cypress@^12.0.0`

I cannot update the cypress dependency. How do I find the right `@testing-library/cypress` version for `cypress@9.5.3` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v8.0.7` says the following in `package.json`:

```js
"peerDependencies": {
  "cypress": "^2.1.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0"
},
```

And it works with a simple test:

```js
import '@testing-library/cypress/add-commands'

it('uses testing library to find heading', () => {
  cy.visit('http://example.com');
  cy.findByRole('heading')
    .should('have.text', 'Example Domain')
})
```

The next version is `v9.0.0` which shows peer dependency of `cypress@12.0.0`, and crashes when used with `cypress@9.5.3`